# UART communication between STM32 et monitor goes well even in case of parity mismatch

Tags: communication, uart, parity

When I configure the stm32 uart in **even** parity mode and the monitor on PC side (using here realterm software) in *odd* parity, the communication goes well.
It goes well when realterm is also configured in **even** parity of course.

But in the same way, when I configure the stm32 uart in **odd** parity mode and realterm in **even** parity, the communication goes well.

I have watched the datas transmitted with a scope on Tx and Rx lanes, one is sending in a parity mode, the other is replying in the other parity mode but everything works well.. which I do not understand.

Any explanation about this ?
Thank you,

Comment: You'll have to inspect the code that you're using.  Drivers and/or application can ignore parity errors.  Use of DMA (instead of PIO) typically forces the UART driver to ignore parity errors, since the specific character frame(s) in error cannot be flagged without aborting the current DMA transfer operation.

Comment: Also, as you said, if there is no logic implemented handling parity error, it's quite normal that everything goes well even in case of parity mismatch. I see on datasheet that USAR_ISR_Pe is raised in case of parity error and that also an interrupt could be generated